# Disable Google Hangouts microphone permission popup

Tags: google-chrome, microphone, popups, google-hangouts

Every time I receive a phone call on my Google Voice number, I get a popup window to https://plus.google.com/talkgadget/webrtcperm?hl=en_US saying "Hangouts needs access to your microphone to make calls. Click the allow button at the top of this window." My laptop doesn't have a microphone, so there's no "allow button" to be clicked, and I won't ever need to make a call from my laptop. Is there a way to stop this popup from appearing without uninstalling the Hangouts extension?